# Deedle series index out of range

Tags: f#, deedle

Hi I'm using the following code:

```
let timeser = ser |> Series.sampleTimeInto(TimeSpan(0,5,0)) Direction.Backward Series.lastValue
```

However often get the following error; System.IndexOutOfRangeException with the Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Does anyone know how to solve this error.

Comment: Suggestion: post some data to make this problem reproducable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to guess what is the problem, because we cannot run your code. But the most obvious reason for the exception is that `Series.lastValue` fails because one of your chunks has no data in it.

Let's say that you have a series with values for just 2 days:

```
let ser = series [ DateTime(2000, 1, 1) => 1.0; DateTime(2000, 1, 2) => 2.0 ]
```

If you try to sample it into 12 hour chunks using `Series.lastValue`, then this fails (because only two of the chunks you get actually contain some values):

```
// This shows you that some of the chunks are empty
ser |> Series.sampleTime (TimeSpan(12,0,0)) Direction.Backward 
// This will fail
ser |> Series.sampleTimeInto(TimeSpan(12,0,0)) Direction.Backward Series.lastValue
```

You can handle this in various ways, but the easiest one would be to return a missing value for chunks with no data:

```
ser |> Series.sampleTimeInto(TimeSpan(12,0,0)) Direction.Backward (fun s -> 
  if s.IsEmpty then nan else Series.lastValue s)
```